# Splitting a text file python

Tags: python

I'm working on a language processor and I'm having problems with filtering text in the word base
Each line reads like

```
00001740 00 a 01 able
00002098 00 a 01 unable
00003552 00 s 02 emergent
```

But I only want it to be like

```
able
unable 
emergent
```

All I could come up with was

```
mfile = ("in.txt","r")
nfile =  ("out.txt","w")
for line in mfile:
    ln1 = mfile.readline()
    a,b,c,d,e = ln1.split(" ")
    nfile.write("%s \n" % (e))
```

And that doesn't work
What do?
I think the problem is mfile.readline()
But I'm not sure

Comment: A question you could ask yourself is: Why isn't this working? If you don't know, **add some print statements to verify your assumptions** about your code. Once you know why it's not working, fix it and iterate. StackOverflow is the place to come when you've run out of ideas as to why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what it is that isn't working, but I'm going to assume your error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'`.

Either way, I'm pretty sure you're proble is because you're not opening the files:

```
mfile = ("in.txt","r")
```

should be

```
mfile = open("in.txt","r")
```

(don't forget to close them afterwards). You have, in the existing case, declared mfile as a tuple of two strings.

Answer (score -1):

here

```
words = []
with open('in.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          line = line.strip()
          line = line.split(' ')
          words.append(line[4])
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     for word in words:
          outfile.write("{0}\n".format(word))
```